# Importing "private" TypeScript declaration from module not exposing it though package.json

Tags: typescript, webpack, node-modules

When importing a component of an npm module not exposed by its package.json like this

```
import {Toolbar} from "@atlaskit/editor-core/dist/esm/ui/Toolbar";
```

tsc / webpack won't find the proper declaration file.

Source and types are available under:

```
node_modules/@atlaskit/editor-core/dist/esm/ui/Toolbar/Toolbar.js
node_modules/@atlaskit/editor-core/dist/types/ui/Toolbar/Toolbar.d.ts
```

How can I properly link the declaration and prevent

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@atlaskit/editor-core/dist/esm/ui/Toolbar'. '.../node_modules/@atlaskit/editor-core/dist/esm/ui/Toolbar/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the package has the declaration file, it's fairly easy to wire up the deep import to use its types.

Add a `typings.d.ts` declaration file to your project to add an ambient module declaration:

```
// assert that an import module of this path HAS types
declare module '@atlaskit/editor-core/dist/esm/ui/Toolbar' {
  // assert that this module contains all exports of the existing declaration file
  export * from '@atlaskit/editor-core/dist/types/ui/Toolbar';
}
```

[Relevant Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-reexport-typings?file=index.tsx)

Comment: Excellent! I was close, but I guess I wouldn't have figured this out, ever! Thanks a bunch!